# Difference between export csv from facebook ui and getting using InsightAPI

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-insights

I'm getting data about my ads using InsightAPI.
(level ads, breakdown country)

Sometimes the column "Results" (clicks) has different values in comparison with the data that was exported using "Reports/Export to Excel" on Facebook Ads Manager UI.

Any explanation why it is different?
Thanks a lot!

First one is: report downloaded using API

[image]

Second one is: get report using facebook ui - reports/export as csv

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the Business Manager is just a WYSIWYG-API-query builder, the difference may occur from different attribution windows set in your API query and in the Business Manager.

Do you specify an attribution window in your query or did you change the attribution window in your business manager?

Comment: This should probably be a comment.

Comment: You can use your browser's web dev tools to see the exact query the Facebook UI is making - probably there's some different option between your call and theirs, different attribution window as suggested by Nils, or different timestamps, etc